# How do you find an element strictly less than integer c in an unordered_set without looping through the whole thing

Tags: c++, unordered-set

I have an `unordered_set` of integers and I want to see if there is an element strictly less than an integer `c` that exists. I want to use `unordered_set::find` but since I'm not finding a single number, how am I able to do this. I could iterate through the entire set but that would take too long. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `std::find_if` or `std::find_if_not`?

Comment: Unfortunately `std::unordered_set` is, well, unordered. So it's not possible to find the required element faster than `O(N)`. Btw. how do you know that it's taking too long? Did you meassure it? If that's your bottleneck you should consider a different, sorted data structure.

Comment: @churill: If there are elements being strictly less, one can abort at the first occurrence. Another approach would be parallel processing of several elements (depending on hardware).

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using a `std::unordered_set` when it is clearly not well suited to this task?